# python code to place x and y label in the middle of tick positions in matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I am trying to create a heatmap by putting gridlines to some particular positions which I have done. Suppose, I tried to make gridlines in positions 358 and 589 in a matrix of length 640,640. After that, I wanted to change the label from 358 to a defined value of 999 and 589 to a specified value of 1023. However, I cannot change the x and y labels in the center position of two gridlines. For example, I have tried the following:

```
data = np.random.rand(640, 640)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(data,cmap='coolwarm')
ax.set_xticks([358,589])
ax.set_yticks([358,589])
ax.set_xticklabels([999,1023])
ax.set_yticklabels([999,1023])
ax.grid(which='major',color='black',linestyle='--',linewidth=1,alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

That create a image as follows:
[Heatmap with customized labelling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tsn3.jpg)

But I want the labeling in the middle of two gridlines instead of the gridline positions. How can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

By default, both the tick labels and the grid lines are decided via the major ticks.  To change this, you could use the minor ticks to position the grid lines and the major ticks for the tick labels:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randn(640, 640).cumsum(axis=0).cumsum(axis=1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(data, cmap='coolwarm')
positions = np.array([358, 589])
ax.set_xticks(positions, minor=True)
ax.set_yticks(positions, minor=True)
borders = np.append(0, positions)
mids = (borders[:-1] + borders[1:]) / 2
ax.set_xticks(mids, [999, 1023], minor=False)
ax.set_yticks(mids, [999, 1023], minor=False)
ax.grid(which='minor', color='black', linestyle='--', linewidth=1, alpha=0.9)
plt.show()
```

[image: grid lines on different positions as major ticks]